# eric5 autocomplete

Tags: python

I've installed Eric5 for python dev. with my portage on gentoo. I can't get any autocomplete in it!

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
os. #<-I've pressed ctrl+space many times but don't get a menu :(
```

Also installed assistant and rope plug-in, but it didn't helped. Configured eric to search completions in API files.

Comment: this is emerge --info eric http://paste.kde.org/492260

Answer (score 4):

In Eric5, go under `Preferences->Editor->APIs` and then check the box `Compile APIs Automatically`.

Select Python2 or Python3 in the `Language` dropdown menu, click the `Add from installed APIs` button and then search for the `Python-X.X.api` that you want.

Click `Apply` and then `OK` and you're done. Also make sure that you have all autocomplete options checked in `Preferences->Editor->Autocompletion`.

Hope it helps